# Which charge is produced when an air balloon is rubbed by dry hair?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, electric-fields, charge

Which charge is produced when an air balloon is rubbed by dry hair?

Comment: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/bring-science-home-static-electricity-attraction/

Answer (score 4):

[Static electricity](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/bring-science-home-static-electricity-attraction/).

The interaction between a balloon and hair is described by the site [Hair, Balloons and Static Electricity](http://sciphile.org/lessons/hair-balloons-and-static-electricity) as:

> Rubbing a balloon on hair transfers negative electrons from the hair to the balloon. As the balloon is removed, it pulls on the hair with an attractive electric force.

Something like:

[image]

[Image source](http://esmartkids.epcor.ca/websites/sse_ca/sky/chargeit.html)

In a very simplified way, resulting in something like:

[image]

[Image source](https://sites.google.com/a/jeffcoschools.us/physics-wiki-2014-2015/home/electrostatics-wiki-project/rubbing-a-balloon-on-the-hair-on-your-head-a-mariano)

**Note:** the '+'s represent a lack of negatively charged electrons, not 'positive charge carriers'

Comment: ok but why does it do that